# Python 2 and 3 compatible way of hiding a decorator from stacktrace

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, decorator, stack-trace

I wrote a decorator that I don't want to show up in the stacktrace. So in Python2 I'd do this:

```
class SneakyDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # [...]
        try:
            self.f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            t, v, tb = sys.exc_info()
            raise v, None, tb.tb_next             # <=== Important line
```

In Python3 I'd do this:

```
class SneakyDecorator:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # [...]
        try:
            self.f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            t, v, tb = sys.exc_info()
            raise v.with_traceback(tb.tb_next)   # <=== Important line
```

**So here is the question: Is there any way to do this in way that is compatible with both Python2 and Python3?** I'd prefer a solution that does not involve two separate code-bases.

I've tried to use the `reraise` function of the `six` module, but the problem is, that this function then appears in the stacktrace.

Same problem if you do it like in this answer: [Exception with original traceback - 2.6-3.X compatible version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555311/exception-with-original-traceback-2-6-3-x-compatible-version).

**Update: The Python3 code does not work!** The call method still shows up in the stacktrace. So the follow-up question is: **Is there a way to do this in Python3 at all?**

Comment: why would you want to make the stack trace less accurate?

Comment: This is just a dupe of that question; at issue here is how to raise an exception with a given traceback in a cross-Python-compatible manner. Isn't it clear from the other post how to do that?

Comment: You won't get anywhere trying to make all of your projects cross-compatible. It is just unproductive.

Comment: @AlexThornton: so we should just give up? That's a.. unproductive attitude there. I do really appreciate it when a framework or library available on PyPI is compatible with both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: I agree that the answer to the linked thread is about as good as it gets.  Your only option in py2 is a `SyntaxError` in py3, so you basically have to do some `if PY2: exec(...)` hackery.

Comment: @mhlester: In my case the decorator is well tested and not relevant to the debugging of client code. So I'd like to hide it, to make the stacktrace more readable. Similar idea as the removal of self.assert(..) function calls in the unittest library.

Comment: @AlexThornton: Well I need to work with Python2.7 right now, but for idealistic reasons I want to support Python3, so...

Comment: I note that the correct method is `with_traceback`, not `with_stacktrace`.

Comment: Your Python 3 version **doesn't work**, actually. The `__call__` method is *still* part of the traceback.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Oh damn, you're right! So I even need to figure out if that is possible at all in Python3!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to make this work is to keep to separate versions of the `__call__` method, because the *exec* itself creates a stack frame! The following, in Python 2 reveals the frame again:

```
class SneakyDecorator:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # [...]
        try:
            self.f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            t, v, tb = sys.exc_info()
            exec("raise v, None, tb.tb_next")
```

results in:

```
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 12, in __call__
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
ValueError: Oi!
```

So using:

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # [...]
    try:
        self.f(*args, **kwargs)
    except:
        t, v, tb = sys.exc_info()
        if sys.version_info[0] <= 2:
            exec("raise v, None, tb.tb_next")
        else:
            raise v.with_traceback(tb.tb_next)
```

won't actually work.

For Python 2, the following has the exact same functionality as your two separate classes:

```
if sys.version_info[0] <= 2:
    _call = '''\
def _call(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # [...]
    try:
        self.f(*args, **kwargs)
    except:
        t, v, tb = sys.exc_info()
        raise v, None, tb.tb_next
'''
    exec(_call)
else:
    def _call(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # [...]
        try:
            self.f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            t, v, tb = sys.exc_info()
            raise v.with_traceback(tb.tb_next)


class SneakyDecorator:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    __call__ = _call
    # niceties, patch up name and qualified name. Optional.
    __call__.__name__ = '__call__'
    __call__.__qualname__ = 'SneakyDecorator.__call__'
```

However, note that for Python 3, the `Exception.with_traceback()` method may allow you to attach a new traceback with the current frame removed, but Python will *tack it back on* the moment you re-raise the exception!

Comment: I tried this, but then in Python2 the exec function shows up in the stacktrace.

Comment: Hmm, ok. So it looks like this is impossible to do in Python3. That's kind of sad.